# Members only area

Tags: php, html, security, session, membership

When building a page that is to be accessible to members only, is the following the correct php:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']): ?>

// all code for page here

<?php endif; ?>
```

Does all of my html / php sit between these two lines?

Are there any other ways of doing this that are better?

What security issues should I be aware of?

My content is not particularly sensitive but may be in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking strictly in terms of writing legible code, why not:

```
<?php
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
   header("Location: login.php");
   exit;
}
?>

<!-- // all code for page here -->
```

Or similar.

Comment: Is there any benefit to adding the `exit;`? Honest question, not trying to pick fault.

Comment: @shanethehat, because it is in the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @shanethehat yes, because if you don't add the `exit;`, the rest of the page (that should be for members only) would be part of the response for everyone. True that any browser automatically follows the `Location` header without showing the response to the user, but there are methods that don't redirect the user so the sensitive information may be exposed.

Comment: Fair enough, dunno why I thought it was unnecessary.  I'll modify my answer too.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak and shanethehat. I hadn't even thought about a redirect for those not logged in yet!

Answer (score 2):

A better way might be:

```
<?php if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']) { header('Location:loginpage.php'); exit; } ?>
```

Then your page can continue as normal, and a user who isn't logged in will get the login page instead.

**Edit:** added the required `exit` call as per the header documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *can* put all your HTML / PHP code in between the conditional if you like. Just be aware that if you do, unauthenticated users won't see *anything* when they hit the page. You may want to put design elements outside the conditional, or at least use an else: before the endif;

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 a = checksession(args); //your own function for checking session
 if(!a)
   header("Location: 401.shtml");  //This can contain advisory regarding login
?>
```

This will be at the top of your page, rest you can decide.